# Дать ответ и закрыть вопрос - нормально ли это?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Встречаются ситуации, когда кто-то из участников предлагает закрыть вопрос (является инициатором или просто дал согласие) и при этом предоставляет свой собственный ответ на вопрос.

Причины закрытия могут быть довольно разными. И в некоторых случаях такое поведение вполне можно было бы оправдать. Например, сначала дал ответ, а некоторое время спустя (т.е. далеко не пара секунд) заметил, что уже имеется дубликат и предложил (или согласился) закрыть вопрос.

Но в общем случае подобное поведение похоже на "захват" вопроса с целью ограничить появление ответов от других участников. Ведь на закрытый вопрос нельзя дать новый ответ, но голосование за уже опубликованные работает в полной мере. Особенно удивительными бывают ситуации вида: проголосовать как "непонятна суть" или "слишком общий", а после этого дать ответ. Может быть понял всё-таки суть?

Считаю, что в подобных случаях участник либо должен отозвать свой голос перед публикацией ответа, либо не предоставлять ответ вовсе. Система, однако, не требует выполнять подобных действий.

Голосующий за закрытие должен понимать, что закрытый вопрос не может получить ответ. Т.о. желание закрыть вопрос, в моём понимании, должно отождествляться с тем фактом что ответ дать нельзя. Если же при этом участник предоставляет ответ, то логично отозвать голос за закрытие. Если этого не сделать - ситуация будет выглядеть несколько противоречивой.

Хотелось бы обсудить с другими участниками сообщества: должны ли мы как-то реагировать на такое поведение или каждый в праве делать то, что явно не запрещено?

P.S. пояснение для закрывающих: суть текущего вопроса в выяснении позиции сообщества по описанным ситуациям.

Comment: Не ясно, какие побочные эффекты могут быть у таких вопросов(/ответов) ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вопрос скорее о моральной составляющей подобного поведения.

Answer (score 9):

Как говорят англичане -- 'it depends'.

Мы недавно в чате обсуждали конкретный пример, когда действия участника могут быть расценены как tactical closing. Подобные закрывашки лично я расцениваю как не очень благовидный поступок.

Сошлюсь на конкретный пример, т.к. я не ханжа "нельзя на мете обсуждать конкретные случаи": надо, ещё как надо! Именно потому что я поддерживаю sharing знаний между активными участниками сообщества, а не просто слил инфу модераторам и забыл.

[Вот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640387/), вот [таймлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/640387/timeline) действий участника.

> По-моему тактикал клозинг чётко виден: 2017-03-16 16:05:19Z участник
>   сообщает о дубликате и через минуту даёт ответ 2017-03-16 16:06:52Z
>   при этом такая простыня текста, что её не наберёшь за минуту -- она
>   явно была заранее подготовлена.

В сочетании с тактическим даунвоутингом (тут не было) я бы расценивал это как злоупотребление и накрутку.

Я лично по ответам не хожу с целью проверить кто как накручивает голоса или ставит тактические минусы, но мне кажется, что участники, которые злоупотребляют чёрными методами получения репутации должны знать, что все их действия логируются и могут быть при случае подняты.

В целом же -- давайте скажем прямо. Существует много де-юре совершенно легальных способов поднять репутацию и при этом не вызывающих упрёков с точки зрения нравственности: ну подумайте головой немного, они ведь даже не скрыты и в ответах на мете проскальзывают порой. Агитирую не переходить на тёмную сторону силы, вот. ;)

Comment: Какой всё-таки итог: одновременное закрытие и ответ - это нормально или нет?

Comment: Как я понял - это не приветствуется, но целиком остаётся на совести участника.

Answer (score 6):

Голосование за закрытие вопроса - это оценка самого вопроса, что он не удовлетворяет принятым нормам для вопросов.

Эта оценка самого вопроса не зависит от ответов, то есть от того, что кто-то решил все же на него ответить и часто носит очень субъективный характер.

Плохо и не допустимо, когда начинают минусовать корректные ответы на вопрос только потому, что кому-то сам вопрос не понравился.

С другой стороны, одновременный ответ на такой вопрос вместе с голосованием за его закрытие имеет тот контекст, что "возможно вам повезет, и кто-то, в том числе может быть и я, ответит на ваш вопрос до его полного закрытия.  Тем не менее это не оправдывает существование вопроса в том виде, как он задан,  и не освобождает его от закрытия".:)

К тому же это позволяет автору вопроса самому закрыть свой вопрос, выбрав наилучший ответ, возможно, из единственного ответа, не дожидаясь, пока вопрос будет многими заминусован до его закрытия путем всеобщего голосования.

Я приведу несколько примеров из своего богатого опыта участия на SO.

Был вопрос, который сходу стали минусовать, потому что представленный в вопросе код был не корректным и далек от решения задачи, описанной в вопросе.

Я написал в комментарии к вопросу, что автор вопроса заслуживает похвалы, так как он самостоятельно пытался решить задачу, но из-за нехватки знаний не смог ее решить.

После этого, прочитав мой комментарий, многие стали плюсовать вопрос, и в результате тенденция с минусами была переломлена, и вопрос вышел в итоге в плюс.

Если бы не мой комментарий в поддержку автора вопроса, то без всяких сомнений, вопрос бы "ушел" в глубокий минус.

Так что наличие плюсов у вопроса или минусов очень часто не связано с качеством вопроса, а носит чисто субъективный характер.

Есть некоторые технические приемы, которые влияют на оценку вопроса другими участниками. Например, отвечающий на вопрос сразу же авансом ставит задавшему вопрос плюс. В этом случае другие участники, видя, что у вопроса уже имеется плюс, не решаются минусовать вопрос, так как их внимание уже в этом случае переключается с вопроса на ответ(ы).

Очень часто бывает так, что более низкие по качеству вопросы, которые не представляют из себя никакого практического или теоретического интереса, имеют много плюсов (отвечающие на вопрос понаставили эти плюсы), в то время как интересные сами по себе вопросы имеют много минусов.

Чтобы не быть голословным, приведу ссылку на свой собственный вопрос
[What is the reason for the existent difference between C and C++ relative to the unary arithmetic operator +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716138/what-is-the-reason-for-the-existent-difference-between-c-and-c-relative-to-the/42942489#42942489)

Этот вопрос имеет аж три минуса, хотя в итоге плюсы перевесили, и результат составляет плюс 6.

Какие претензии могут быть к этому вопросу? Вопрос написан довольно внятно, даны ссылки на стандарты, показаны примеры кода, демонстрирующие проблему, а также показано, почему возник вопрос. Тем не менее вопрос был сходу заминусован совершенно без веских оснований.

Есть категория участников обычно с низкой квалификацией (по крайней мере их репутация по сравнению с периодом их пребывания на форуме выглядит крайне не серьезной), от которых пользы на форуме нет, но которые активно минусуют или закрывают вопросы.

Поэтому лично я, когда вижу, что вопрос начинающего программиста может получить много минусов от таких бесполезных участников форума, порой отвечаю на вопрос и голосую за его закрытие, чтобы позволить начинающему программисту избежать многих минусов к его вопросу, так как редко кто минусует уже закрытые вопросы - интерес к таким вопросам пропадает со стороны праздно "шатающихся" на форуме участников.

Некоторые начинающие программисты понимают, в какую ситуацию они попали, и быстро выбирают лучший ответ из тех, что успели написать, тем самым закрывая вопрос естественным образом. Некоторым начинающим программистам такая идея в голову не приходит, а потому вопрос долго висит не закрытым, и все, кому не лень, минусуют этот вопрос, что число минусов для вполне нормального вопроса может доходить до минус 10 и более.

Comment: Сложно дать корректный ответ, если вопрос закрывается как не совсем корректный. Минусы ответу в таком случае могут в том числе показывать нежелание сообщества видеть вовсе вопрос на сайте. Т.к. известно, что даже глубоко заминусованный вопрос не будет автоматически удалён, если есть ответы с голосами "за" (вроде бы +2 должно быть хотя бы).

Comment: @alexolut Я в качестве ответа на ваш комментарий дополнил свой основной ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, нормально, хотя и не частая ситуация.

"Закрытие" вопроса означает, что он не подходит для SO (широк, неясен, бесполезен, оффтопик, и т.п.). Один голос за закрытие не означает, что вопрос не может быть отвечен. Тем более, что голос за закрытие - лишь частное мнение, которое вовсе не обязательно будет поддержано другими.

Наврядли кто-то пользуется этим "*с целью ограничить появление ответов от других участников*"

Comment: ох, я б вас удивил...но тут нельзя, к сожалению, показывать личности, которые так делают

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может быть опишите свой опыт в ответе, без указания имен?

Comment: А смысл? Без указания ссылок на данные действия это будет всего лишь пустословием.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский упоминание в каментах даже без описания ситуации - еще большее пустословие :-(

Comment: Хм, чем же? Это уже вопросы к системе, не ко мне. А ситуация описана в топике: ответ на вопрос и тут же голос за закрытие.

Comment: *"Закрытие не означает, что вопрос не может быть отвечен."* На закрытый вопрос нельзя дать **новый** ответ. Так что как раз таки означает.

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе свою позицию.

Comment: @alexolut Ваше "как раз таки означает" - это ответ не на пост **Kromster**, а на Вашу творческую переработку его поста. Прочитайте и сравните, что им написано, и что Вы процитировали. **Kromster** прав - пока вопрос не закрыт, на него можно ответить, даже если есть голоса за закрытие. И факт ответа на вопрос не запрещает ответившему участнику иметь мнение, что вопрос не подходит для SO (и высказать его в форме голоса за закрытие).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский модераторам маякните )

Comment: @Kromster теперь вы должны проголосовать за закрытие этого вопроса :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin в чате, кстати, есть мои сообщения об этом  ;-) Но не модератору, а в разговоре с участником. И участник, в некотором роде, признал сий факт. А второй уже забанен :D Правда пока по другой причине.... а вот на мету нельзя, закон!) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не только признал, но и вроде обещал исправиться)

Comment: @NickVolynkin вовсе не должен, и не буду :-P

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на мете можно и нужно приводить конкретные примеры. Та тема просит совсем другого не делать.

Comment: @Akina я процитировал именно то, что было в тексте ответа на тот момент. См. [список ревизий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4960/revisions).

Comment: Отметка вопроса как дупликата, начиная с некоторого уровня репутации, приводит к мгновенному закрытию вопроса одним-единственным голосом. Это иногда оправдано, но в большинстве случаев хотелось бы иметь опцию просто спокойно проголосовать за закрытие одним голосом, а не закрывать вопрос немедленно.

Comment: @AnT это зависит от наличия золотого знака за метку, насколько я понимаю, а не от репутации. Обходной (кривенький) путь - изменить метки, проголосовать, откатить метки.

Answer (score 2):

Да, ответить на вопрос и проголосовать за закрытие как дубликата - это нормально.

Это позволяет дать краткий ответ под конкретную ситуацию и указать, что подробно всё расписано в другом ответе, который выбирается как основной при закрытии.

Пример:

[JavaScript forin не пробегает по индексам массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527081/178988)
2016-05-24 13:23:33Z [Ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527091/178988)
2016-05-24 13:23:45Z [Голос за закрытие как дубликат](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512990/178988)

Как видно, в первом ответе кратко говоритcя о разряженном массиве, а во втором подробно расписано, что там происходит и как оно устроено.

Comment: Об этом у меня сказано во втором параграфе вопроса, в принципе.

Comment: @alexolut, 12 секунд подпадают под фразу _"т.е. далеко не пара секунд"?_ o_O

Comment: Технически, да :) Но на самом деле я просто не обратил внимания на тайм-штампы. Вашу позицию понял, спасибо.

Comment: А всё таки, о каких первом и втором ответах идёт речь? Можете добавить прямые ссылки?

Comment: @alexolut, ну стоят же ссылки. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527091/178988 & http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513039/178988

Comment: Второй **ссылки на ответ** нет в тексте. А раз уж ответы подразумеваются разные, то почему вопросы должны считаться дубликатами? А коли уж вопросы дубликаты, то и ответ должен быть единый (один), а не два.

Comment: @alexolut, подразумеваются частный и общий. Частный может быть закрыт как дубликат общего, если там этот случай рассмотрен.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение - да.
Мелкий вопрос, который мгновенно решается, и автору вопроса не придется искать ответ непонятно где и сколько. Но сам вопрос для 99.9% посетителей SO не приносит никакой пользы, поэтому его лучше закрыть.

Правда, если посмотреть, то среди вопросов большинство таких, которые решают очень частные проблемы. Более того, каждый вопрошающий формулирует проблему по-своему, так что, например, вопрос с выходом за пределы массива может формулироваться в диапазоне от "выводятся какие-то кракозябры" до "ошибка в компиляторе" :). При этом по сути бессмысленно объявлять его как дубль вопроса "выход за границы массива"...

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что предполагается давать ответ, который по мнению отвечающего полезен исключительно ТС и более никому?

Comment: @alexolut Да, вероятно, это можно назвать и так. С последующим закрытием вопроса. Какая разница, какой будет висяк - не принесший никому пользы или принесший хотя бы одному человеку?

Comment: Закрытие вопроса всегда предполагает возможность приведения его в порядок. Там так и написано: "Требует правки". Если вопрос невозможно привести в порядок - он должен быть удалён. Получение же автором вопроса готового ответа резко уменьшает вероятность того, что он приведёт его в порядок.

Comment: `Более того, каждый вопрошающий формулирует проблему по-своему` именно поэтому дубликаты позиционируются как плюс, а не как минус. Решение проблемы можно будет найти по разным формулировкам.

Comment: @vp_arth еще возникает вопрос, где должен быть размещён ответ, если отвечающий предлагает закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: @vp_arth Возможно, я плохо слежу... Но пока что мне ни разу не попался "требующий правки" вопрос, который был бы приведен в порядок...

Comment: В [истории на переоткрытие](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) можно посмотреть по резолюциям "Открыть повторно".