# Где размещать ответ при закрытии как "дубликат"?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, дубликаты

По стопам вопроса [Дать ответ и закрыть вопрос - нормально ли это?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4957/176217), в котором, как я могу судить, сообщество решило, что одновременное голосование за закрытие и публикация ответа в принципе допустимо, родился иной вопрос:

Где следует размещать ответ при закрытии как "дубликат": в закрываемом вопросе или в том, который рассматривается как первичный?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ надо размещать там, куда он подходит.

Например, если есть эталонный вопрос с подробным решением, писать туда кучу частных каждый раз, когда некий вопрос закрывается как дубликат - это бред. Да и вообще, если есть желание помочь спрашивающему, то ответ, вероятно, будет использовать нечто из вопроса, соответственно, под другой вопрос он может несколько не подходить.

А вот если есть желание расписать какой-то нерассмотренный вариант, то можно это в эталонном вопросе сделать.

Comment: А зачем писать частный ответ, если уже есть ответ, покрывающий общий случай?

Comment: @alexolut, а почему бы нет?

Comment: В каких случаях это может быть полезным?

Comment: @alexolut, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4971/178988

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что ответ должен размещаться там, где закрытие не планируется, т.е. в первичном вопросе. Это хорошо хотя бы с той точки зрения, что пришедший из поисковика человек сможет видеть все ответы на одной странице (вариант слишком большого кол-ва ответов под одним вопросом пока не рассматриваем) и не потребует лишних кликов для поиска наиболее подходящего ответа под вопросами, отмеченными как "дубликат".