# Я ответил на вопрос на который не собирался отвечать, более того я его отметил дубликаом

Tags: обсуждение

Господа, на сайте появился [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730704/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C-input-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0), я его отметил дубликатом, но в тот момент, когда сильные сайта сего решали закрывать его или нет, я для себя в редакторе решил проверить свои знания и скопировал код своего ответа с другого вопроса, поковырялся, потом я отменил ответ и закрыл вкладку. Каково было мое удивление, когда я увидел, что система сама вставила мой ответ. Мои предположения, что система решила что я хочу тоже ответить в момент закрытия вопроса и вставила мой ответ, это нормально?

P.S. Для тех, кто решил что это дубликат, вопрос совершенно о другом, прочитайте вопрос внимательнее...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дать ответ и закрыть вопрос - нормально ли это?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4957/%d0%94%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: не далее как сегодня так же поступил: проголосовал за дубликат - дал кратенький ответ по ситуации у ТС

Comment: я не о том, я не собирался отвечать, я для себя это делал  пока я в редакторе ковырялся, система вставила мой ответ

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "отменил ответ"?

Comment: @Air, скорее всего, имел место misclick. Может, случайно нажали `Ctrl+Enter` или "Отправить"...

Comment: в редакторе есть кнопка "сбросить",  я ее нажал и закрыл вкладку в браузере, но потом  увидел свой ответ в вопросе

Comment: тогда такое похоже на [meta-tag:дефект], интересны способы воспроизведения ситуации

Comment: нет, точно, нажал сбросить)))  и закрыл вкладку, тем более, что в тот момент когда я начал ковыряться, на вопрос уже ответили

Comment: @mymedia, я тоже так подумал и решил переспросить

Comment: *Мои предположения … это нормально?* — предположения всегда нормальны.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а Вы в ромбовидные в этот раз не планируете?

Comment: @alexolut, с прошлых выборов я сменил место работы и теперь не располагаю достаточным (с моей точки зрения) временем на модерацию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в следующий раз выбирайте работу правильно :)