# Минусануть или закрыть. Тонкая грань

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, голоса-против

В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) написано:

> Вопросы следует закрывать если:
>
> ...
>
> они **неясно сформулированы**, слишком размыты или **не понятно, в чем именно заключается вопрос**;

Также при наведении на значок "стрелка вниз" (который "минусануть") написано:

> Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться, **он не понятен** или не несёт
> пользы.

Вопрос: где та тонкая грань между "вопрос непонятен, поэтому надо минусануть" и "вопрос неясно сформулирован, надо проголосовать за закрытие по причине *Непонятна суть вопроса*"?

P.S. Очень подозреваю, что этот вопрос уже где-нибудь да поднимался, но как ни вбивал в поиск, не смог найти подобного. Если кто-то сможет, отметьте дубликат, почитаю обсуждение в оригинале.

Comment: [Почему «или»?](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/SpicyConsciousCornsnake-small.gif)

Comment: @defaultlocale, насколько я понимаю, это разные действия и предназначены для разного. Если нет, не могли бы Вы пояснить в каких случаях стоит использовать оба действия, а в каких одно из?

Comment: Согласен, это разные действия, друг с другом никак не связанные. Нужно минусовать минусуйте, нужно закрывать закрывайте. Вроде одно не мешает другому, поэтому не совсем ясно что Вас смущает.

Comment: Смущает разница между ситуацией, когда нужно минусовать и ситуацией, когда нужно закрывать. Вот мне не понятен вопрос от слова совсем, допустим. Его стоит минусануть, закрыть или и то и другое?

Comment: А без четких инструкций вы уже не можете? Действуйте по наитию

Comment: @АндрейNOP опыт подсказывает, что по наитию – не всегда правильно.

Comment: А это не важно, для закрытия одного голоса не достаточно все равно, а минус вообще мало на что влияет кроме рейтинга. Если бы все было однозначно и просто, люди были бы не нужны.

Comment: Если по Вашему мнению вопрос подходит под условия как голосования «против», так и закрытия ввиду непонятности, то, да, его нужно и минусануть и закрыть. Мне не совсем понятно почему это Вас удивляет. Есть какие-то причины думать что одно из этих действий делать не нужно?

Comment: @defaultlocale, как одно всегда думалось, что одно для одного рода ситуаций, другое – для другого. Как-то избыточно на мой взгляд выглядит минус + закрытие. Хотя, видимо, я не прав

Comment: как раз очень логично все - если вопрос непонятен, то его можно закрывать, а если вопрос заслуживает закрытия, то минуса он заслуживает и подавно.

Comment: @Эникейщик не соглашусь про обязательный минус при закрытии. Например, вопрос может быть интересным, то не подходящим для сайта по тем или иным критериям. Хороший пример - всякие [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе].

Comment: Я думаю, если вопрос лично вам в самом деле не понятен, то стоит  пройти мимо. Другое дело, если вам без сомнений очевидно, что вопрос не относится к сфере IT (например, он явно о футболе), тогда его можно и закрывать

Answer (score 4):

Как уже упоминалось в комментариях - одно другому не мешает. Инструменты сайта не эксклюзивны в плане использования. Например, могут быть довольно неоднозначные ситуации:

- [Дать ответ и закрыть вопрос - нормально ли это?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4957/176217)
- Принять ответ галочкой и минусануть его же
- Отметить комментарий полезным и флагануть его

При этом стоит заметить, что [возможность минусовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) предоставляется при репутации 125, а для [голоса о закрытии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) уже 3000. Т.е. при наличии желания закрыть может просто не быть возможности (не хватает репы), тогда ставится минус. Ещё, конечно, можно и [тревогу влепить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) - нужно всего-то 15 реп.

Я действую примерно так: если вопрос не соответствует тематике, то голосую закрытием; если вопрос не нравится (по разным причинам), то минус; если и то, и другое - то совмещаю.